# Firemonkey custom Notification sound not working

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I hope I am just missing something somewhere,I want a custom notification sound to be played when my local notification is fired.

On a new form I dropped down 2 buttons, btnnotification and btnmediaplayer

```
procedure TForm1.btnnotificationClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    MyNotification : TNotification;
begin
    MyNotification := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;
    try
        MyNotification.EnableSound := True;
        MyNotification.SoundName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'Siren.mp3');
        MyNotification.Name := 'mynote';
        MyNotification.AlertBody := 'Test';
        MyNotification.FireDate := Now;
        ShowMessage(MyNotification.SoundName); //<-- Points towards a valid filepath
        NotificationCenter1.ScheduleNotification(MyNotification);
    finally
        //MyNotification.DisposeOf;
    end;
end;
```

I added the Siren file to the internal assets in deployment, the notification fires but there is no sound, I then added another button and this time I am just using a TMediaplayer

```
procedure TForm1.btnmediaplayerClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    MediaPlayer1.FileName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'Siren.mp3');
    MediaPlayer1.Play;
    ShowMessage(MediaPlayer1.FileName);//<--Points towards the same path as the notification
end;
```

With the TMediaplayer it works no problems, which means the file does exists, I have now tried this with 2 different devices : Xperia Z2 And a Samsung Note 2 both running Andriod V4.4.2 , 
and both devices have their notification volume set to max but still no sound.

**Update 1**

- I tried it on a Samsung Tab3 running 4.1.2 which means its not a 4.4.2 issue
- I tried manually copying the file in the com.andriod.project folder

but still no sound on the notification.

**Solved** : You need to have the sound stored Externally and use GetSharedDocumentsPath, storing it internally and using GetDocumentsPath doesn't work

Comment: It looks, you have solved the problem yourself. Please post your solution with some detailed explanations as an answer, so that it your question is recognized as an answered question.

Answer (score -1):

use `property ReceiveLocalNotification`.
you must in this property use yours sound

```
procedure TForm1.NotificationCenter1ReceiveLocalNotification(Sender: TObject;
  ANotification: TNotification);

begin

   MediaPlayer1.FileName:=TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'Siren.mp3');

end;
```

Comment: I've attempted to fix the formatting in your answer. I'm not familiar with firemonkey so don't know the syntax - please review what I've done and correct anywhere where I've created an error.

Comment: This is not the right answer, because this will only start playing the Siren.mp3 once you hit the notification and that will open your App and play the file, if your App is already in the foreground this will do nothing or if you didn't tap on the notification it would also do nothing, Look at my Solved statement at the bottom of my question